# Periodically running script with periods of time idle?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, time, scheduler

I'm looking for some help understanding and using the python scheduler to be able create a function to call scripts at certain times and also idle at certain times.

In the most generic way possible I would like to create a script to do the following:

- During the hours of 01:30 and 23:50 it must run every 3 minutes (+ or - a random of 60 seconds)
- Every time the function runs it must call several scripts.
- At 23:50 it must run a different script and cease running the previous scripts until the time gets back round to 01:30 in which the routine starts again.

I'll try and simplify below:

```
01:30 to 23:50: Calls "MAIN.py" and "SEC.py"
23:50: Calls "DO.py"
23:50 to 01:30: Idles (Does nothing during these hours)
The loop will now start again
```

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

I've been looking at: [Timer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-object) and [Sched](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html#scheduler-objects) but nothing seems to work how I try it..

Comment: Have you looked at the `time` module?

Comment: @KaranGoek yeah, I've had a look at that, scheduler and a few other type of scheduler library's but can't get anything working as needed and for such s simple task it makes it mightily frustrating

Comment: you can write a little shell script to do this, and use utility called `cron`.

Comment: @Vor yeah I should of mentioned I can't use cron for this

Comment: Why can't you use cron?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Windows based PC(s) and it needs to be semi-portable without any needed setup

Answer (score -1):

Windows have Task Scheduler. You can schedule a recurring task which runs at 01:30 every day which starts a script which register task to run every three minutes. Also, schedule a task at 23:50 which will run a script that disables the task that runs every 3 minutes, and then continues with running DO.py.

Comment: I had a look at that but the problem with going down that route is that it's not easily made portable to switch and play around with it on different computers

Comment: @Hyflex: you can write a script that will register and deregister the 01:30 and 23:50 task. Otherwise, your other option would be to use a third party cron (e.g. cronw, cygwin, pycron, etc) or do a little bit of time math (the datetime module makes this easy) and sleep() as necessary.

Comment: I've had my own go before trying to recreate it as for my needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559933/complete-a-task-during-certain-time-frames-within-a-python-script

I'm still really nooby with python but I'm trying to learn from snippits and help docs and also youtube videos but it's taking it's time... I'm slowly getting there though.